# Android GridView: How to make the GridView adapt to its content height?

Tags: android, gridview

I have a GridView, and I want that it automatically adjusts to its content's height.

This is my **layout file**:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/fuer_"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:layout_span="2"
                    android:layout_column="0"/>

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/medikament_"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <Spinner
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/spinner_medikament"
                    android:layout_column="1" />


            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow31"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <Button
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/medikament_erstellen"
                    android:id="@+id/button_medikament_erstellen"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_span="2" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/verschreiber_"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <Spinner
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/spinner_verschreiber"
                    android:layout_column="1" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow33"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <Button
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/behandler_erstellen"
                    android:id="@+id/button_behandler_erstellen"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_span="2" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow00"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <GridView
                    android:id="@+id/gridview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="400dp"
                    android:columnWidth="90dp"
                    android:numColumns="9"
                    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
                    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_span="2">

                </GridView>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow50"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView51"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/beginn_"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText_beginn"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:inputType="none"
                    android:editable="false"/>

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow0"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <RadioGroup android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/mode_radio_group"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_span="2">
                    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_immer"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/iimmer"
                        android:checked="true"/>
                    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_enddatum"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/enddatum"
                        android:checked="false"
                        android:layout_gravity="right" />
                </RadioGroup>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow56"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView53"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/ende_"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText_ende"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:inputType="none"
                    android:editable="false"
                    android:enabled="false" />

            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

And this is my **adapter class**:

```
 public class MedikamentGridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    private long patientId;

    public MedikamentGridViewAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFS_FILE, 0);
        this.patientId = prefs.getLong(Constants.SELECTED_PATIENT_ID, 1);
    }

    public MedikamentGridViewAdapter(Context context, long patientId) {
        this.context = context;
        this.patientId = patientId;
        this.prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFS_FILE, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 54;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // determine columns from position
        View view;
        int rest = position % 9;
        if(rest == 0){
            view = new TextView(context);
            ((TextView)view).setText("ABCDEFGHI");
        } else {
            view = new EditText(context);
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: use this layout:https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid

Comment: no, that did not work for me

Comment: your questino is about "GridView" but the layout in your question does not contain a "GridView" but a "TableLayout"

Comment: Look carefully, inside a table row is a GridView...